# How to display the elements of a 5*5 matrix in the following way?

Tags: c, data-structures

I want to display the output of 5*5 matrix in the following way:

Input:

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 0
1 3 5 7 9
2 4 6 8 0
1 4 3 7 0
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 0 9 0 0 7 3 4 1 2 1 6 7 8 9 7 8 6 4 3 5
```

I have written the below program, but I can't get output like the above. What is the mistake?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{ 
    int i, j, m, n, a[5][5];
    scanf("%d%d",  & m,  & n);
    if (m >= 1 && m <= 5 && n >= 1 && n <= 5)
    {
       for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
       {
          for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
          {
             scanf("%d", a[i][j]);
          }
       }
       if (m == 5 && n == 5)
       {
          for (i = 0; i == 0; i++)
          {
             for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
             {
                printf("%d", a[i][j]);
             }
          }
          for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
          {
             for (j = n - 1; j == n - 1; j++)
             {
                printf("%d", a[i][j]);
             }
          }
          for (i = n - 1; i == n - 1; i++)
          {
             for (j = n - 2; j >= 0; j--)
             {
                printf("%d", a[i][j]);
             }
          }
          for (i = n - 2; i >= n - 4; i--)
          {
             for (j = 0; j == 0; j++)
             {
                printf("%d", a[i][j]);
             }
          }
          for (i = n - 4; i == n - 4; i++)
          {
             for (j = n - 4; j <= n - 2; j++)
             {
                printf("%d", a[i][j]);
             }
          }
          for (i = n - 3; i == n - 3; i++)
          {
             for (j = n - 2; j >= n - 4; j--)
             {
                printf("%d", a[i][j]);
             }
          }
       }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To start with, you should first indent your code, so others can read it.

Comment: You should clarify and show us what wrong output you get from your program as well as the expected output. It also helps if you wrote in text in your question that you want to write the numbers of the matrix by sprialing inwards through the elements.

Comment: You could use a recursive approach. Write a function that moves around each of the four outer edges of your square, and then it calls itself with the inner square.

Comment: @JoakimGebart I can't any output on the screen. It is empty.

Comment: Put a newline character `\n` into each of your `printf`. That way you can see how far you're getting. Remove the newlines once everything is working.

Comment: Perhaps you should start with a program that simply prints the elements of the matrix, debug that, and go from there. SO overflow is not the appropriate place to bootstrap your most basic coding skills.

Comment: first : `scanf("%d",a[i][j]);` should be `scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
if(m>=1 && m<=5 && n>=1 && n<=5)
    {
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
    scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
    }
    }
```

you will get output displayed on screen and use

```
printf("%d\t",a[i][j]);
```

to display output clearly
make this changes to the code, you are not looping through the matrix properly,

```
 #include<stdio.h>
int main()
{ 
int i,j,m,n,a[5][5];
scanf("%d%d",&m,&n);
if(m>=1 && m<=5 && n>=1 && n<=5)
{
for(i=0;i<m;i++)
{
for(j=0;j<n;j++)
{
scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
}
}
if(m==5 && n==5)
{
for(i=0;i==0;i++)
{
for(j=0;j<n;j++)
{ 
printf("%d\t",a[i][j]);
}
}
for(i=1;i<n;i++)
{
for(j=n-1;j==n-1;j++)
{
printf("%d\t",a[i][j]);
}
}
for(i=n-1;i==n-1;i++)
{
for(j=n-2;j>=0;j--)
{
printf("%d\t",a[i][j]);
}
}
for(i=n-2;i>=n-4;i--)
{
for(j=0;j==0;j++)
{
printf("%d\t",a[i][j]);
}
}   
for(i=n-4;i==n-4;i++)
{ 
for(j=n-4;j<=n-2;j++)
{
printf("%d\t",a[i][j]);
} 
} 
for(i=n-3;i<=n-2;i++)
{
for(j=n-2;j==n-2;j++)
{
  printf("%d\t",a[i][j]);
}
}
for(i=n-2;i==n-2;i++)
{
for(j=n-3;j>=n-4;j--)
{
  printf("%d\t",a[i][j]);
}
}
 for(i=n-3;i==n-3;i++)
{
for(j=n-4;j<=n-3;j++)
{
  printf("%d\t",a[i][j]);
}
}
} 
}
return 0;
}
```

this loop is for 5*5 only as you coded.

Answer (score 0):

5*5 sample

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){ 
    int i,j,m,n,a[5][5];
    //scanf("%d %d",&m,&n);
    //if(m>=1 && m<=5 && n>=1 && n<=5){
    m = n = 5;
    for(i=0;i<m;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    int side_size = m;
    int row = 0, col = 0;//start point
    int side = side_size -1;
    while(side > 1){
        for(i = 0; i<side ;++i)
            printf("%d ", a[row][col++]);//MOVE RIGHT
        for(i = 0; i<side ;++i)
            printf("%d ", a[row++][col]);//MOVE DOWN
        for(i = 0; i<side ;++i)
            printf("%d ", a[row][col--]);//MOVE LEFT
        for(i = 0; i<side ;++i)
            printf("%d ", a[row--][col]);//MOVE UP
        ++row;++col;
        side -= 2;
    }
    printf("%d\n", a[row][col]);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use **go forward** and **turn right** approach

```
int max_x = 4;
int min_x = 0;
int max_y = 4;
int min_y = 0;
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int direction = 0; // 0-RIGHT, 1-DOWN, 2-LEFT, 3-UP
int count = 0;

int go_forward(){
    switch(direction){
        case 0: 
            if( x+1 > max_x ){ min_y++; return 1; }
            else x++;
            break;
        case 1: 
            if( y+1 > max_y ){ max_x--; return 1; }
            else y++;
            break;
        case 2: 
            if( x-1 < min_x ){ max_y--; return 1; }
            else x--;
            break;
        case 3: 
            if( y-1 < min_y ){ min_x++; return 1; }
            y--;
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}

int turn_right(){
    direction = (direction+1)%4; // 0-RIGHT, 1-DOWN, 2-LEFT, 3-UP
}

int main(){
    /* int matrix[5][5]={    { 1,  2,  3,  4,  5},
                    { 6,  7,  8,  9, 10},
                    {11, 12, 13, 14, 15},
                    {16, 17, 18, 19, 20},
                    {21, 22, 23, 24, 25}}; //TEST */
    //get matrix from input

    int cango;
    do{
        printf("%d ", matrix[y][x]);
        count++;
        cango = go_forward();
        if( cango!=0 ){
            turn_right();
            cango = go_forward();
        }
    }while(cango == 0 && count < 25);

    return 0;
}
```